# Can I call a keyword using variable in Robot framework

Tags: robotframework

I have a robot keyword defined as below in my robot framework.

```
*** Keywords***
sample keyword
     Log inside keyword
```

I want to call this keyword in my testcase using a variable as shown below.

```
*** Test Cases***
Sample Test
    ${sample_var}=   Catenate keyword # assigns value "keyword" to var ${sample_var}
    sample ${sample_var} #calls keyword sample keyword
```

Is there any way i can implement this in Robot Framework?

Thanks in advance

Comment: can be implemented using **Run Keyword**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do this with the [Run Keyword](http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/libraries/BuiltIn.html#Run%20Keyword) keyword (using the pipe-separated format for clarity):

```
*** Test cases ***
| Example
| | ${keyword}= | Set Variable | Should not be equal
| | Run keyword | ${keyword} | Hello | World
```

Comment: Thanks Bryan. I have used the same.